# Convert date to MM//DD HH/MM

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How do you convert date to MM/DD HH/MM

example: 04-05 12:42

Comment: Looks like that question is about converting a string to a date, so not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on SQL Server 2012, use `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM-dd HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `MONTH`, `DAY`, `HOUR`, `MINUTE` functions in T-SQL and concatenate your results into a string form like:

```
CONCAT(STRING(HOUR(created_at)), ':', RIGHT(STRING(MINUTE(created_at)), 3)) AS hour_min
```

Where the `created_at` is your timestamp column. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is using BigQuery flavored SQL